# How to minimize an ubuntu docker image which needs only git, cron and openjdk-8-jre

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, docker-image

Testing some docker project so after playing with alpine, I would like to use ubuntu:bionic for production. I decided to roll out my own image but the problem is that it's 600MB+ .

```
REPOSITORY                               TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntucronjava                           latest              101aed049a54        6 minutes ago       600MB
<none>                                   <none>              d0298b733b5f        13 minutes ago      610MB
```

Below is my dockerfile

```
ROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q software-properties-common

RUN apt-get --no-install-recommends -y install cron openjdk-8-jre git-core curl python-pip && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
mkdir -p /opt/cert/gitlab  /opt/features && \
chmod -R  777 /opt/* && \
touch /var/log/gitcron.log

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
ENV GIT_URL https://xxxx:yyyyy@gitzzzzzzz.com/smartgrid/core-platform/deployment/dev/home.git

COPY cert/ /opt/cert/gitlab/

RUN git config --global http.sslCert /opt/cert/gitlab/gitlab.xxxxxxxxxxx_client.crt && \
git config --global http.sslKey /opt/cert/gitlab/gitlab.xxxxxxxxx_client.key && \
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64" >> ~/.bashrc && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
git clone $GIT_URL /opt/features

RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * *  sh -c 'cd /opt/features && git pull' >> /var/log/gitcron.log") | crontab

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/gitcron.log
```

I have noticed some packages are getting installed like `adwaita-icon-theme` or `x11-common` that I am doubtful they are really needed in this docker ubuntu server container . Below is a snippet of the output

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adwaita-icon-theme ca-certificates-java dconf-gsettings-backend
  dconf-service fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core git-man
  glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme
  humanity-icon-theme java-common libasn1-8-heimdal libasound2 libasound2-data
  libasyncns0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libbsd0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2
  libcolord2 libcroco3 libcups2 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libdatrie1 libdconf1
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
  libdrm2 libedit2 libegl-mesa0 libegl1 libelf1 libepoxy0 liberror-perl
  libflac8 libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libgbm1 libgdbm-compat4
  libgdbm5 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7 libgl1
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0
  libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgtk-3-0
  libgtk-3-common libharfbuzz0b libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libice6 libicu60 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
  libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libllvm6.0 libnghttp2-14 libnspr4
  libnss3 libogg0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libperl5.26 libpixman-1-0 libpng16-16 libproxy1v5
  libpsl5 libpulse0 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
  librest-0.7-0 libroken18-heimdal librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librtmp1
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-db libsensors4 libsm6 libsndfile1
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libvorbis0a
  libvorbisenc2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1-mesa
  libwayland-server0 libwind0-heimdal libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data
  libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0
  libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1
  libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6
  libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxml2
  libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxt6
  libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 multiarch-support
  openjdk-8-jre-headless perl perl-modules-5.26 python python-minimal
  python-pip-whl python2.7 python2.7-minimal shared-mime-info ubuntu-mono ucf
  x11-common x11-utils xkb-data
```

Full output of the build here on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/UdSxaBQi) . I would be grateful if there are ways to remove unnecessary packages and keep the image smaller.

Best Regards

Comment: Is there a reason why you have decided not to go with alpine? It was created for this type of usage.

Comment: If you plan on building it multiple times I wouldn't use git like that, do you really need all the commits? you could have used `--depth=1`. Also, since this seems to be a java app, you could use a multistage build, that would reduce the size of the final image.

Comment: @McKracken we have always used ubuntu for production systems. But we are using alpine for any other java deployment that doesn't need the git part. So there are some files we want to be able to update and make available to the application.  There are other scenarios that this regular pull covers as well

Comment: I understand that part, but you can have git in alpine. It is literally just one 'RUN apk --update add git openssh' away. It is way easier to just add all the packages you need to a minimal distribution, that try to trim fat from Bionic.